# How can I create a structural model in CSEM using RStudio with three variables, one mediator, and one moderator?

Tags: r, structural-equation-model

I need to create a structural model in Csem. It contains 3 variables: a mediation and a moderator. [image]Visual model:

```
model = '

#Reflective model 
  jobSatisfaction =~ jobSatisfaction_1 + jobSatisfaction_2 + jobSatisfaction_3 + jobSatisfaction_4 + jobSatisfaction_5 + jobSatisfaction_6
  orgSupport =~ orgSupport_1 + orgSupport_2 + orgSupport_3 + orgSupport_4 + orgSupport_5 + orgSupport_6 + orgSupport_7 + orgSupport_8
  performance =~ performance_1 + performance_2 + performance_3 + performance_4

#Structural model
jobSatisfaction ~ orgSupport

performance ~ orgSupport + jobSatisfaction  #+ orgSupport.jobSatisfaction

'
# Return summary
summarize(out)
#fail
assess(out)
```

Comment: Please disable the automated translator in your browser or move to [es.so].

Comment: What's the issue exactly? What's wrong with the code you have? Without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862), we can't run anything